# Show that $\min(a,b,d) \leq \frac{ac-bd}{a-b+c-d} \leq \max(a,b,d)$ holds

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

Either of 1 or 2 holds.

1. $a > b, b<c, c>d$ and $d<a$
2. $a < b, b>c, c<d$ and $d>a$.

I wish to show that
$$\min(a,b,d) \leq \cfrac{ac-bd}{a-b+c-d} \leq \max(a,b,d)$$

I thought of splitting into 9 cases. However, is there any simpler way? I am open to any help to start.

Comment: Splitting into multiple cases, seems to be easiest option. Can't see a more direct way to this.

Comment: @TenaliRaman Is there any way to reduce the number of cases?

Comment: The problem is symmetric in $b$ and $d$, so you can suppose that $b\le d$.

Comment: Assuming $b\le d$, one has $min = b$ and $max = a$ in case 1, and $min = a$ and $max = d$ in case 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the conditions can be written as

1. $min(a,c) > max(b,d)$
2. $min(b,d) > max(a,c)$

Further, due to symmetry, we can set $b \ge d$ and now the conditions become

1. $min(a,c) > b \ge d$
   $min(a,b,d) =d$
   $max(a,b,d) = a$
2. $b \ge d > max(a,c)$
   $min(a,b,d) = a$
   $max(a,b,d) = b$

In case 1, multiply the inequality by (positive) $a+c-b-d$, simplify and factor to get

$$-(a-d)(c-d) \le 0 \le (a-d)(a-b)$$

In case 2, multiply by $b+d - a-c$ and simplify to

$$ -(d-a)(b-a) \le 0 \le (b+c)(b-a)$$

Both of these are true, so the original inequality is also true in both cases.